# Exclude test dependency resolution from `sbt compile`

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy

When running `sbt compile`, dependencies marked as `test` are still resolved even though they are not later included later in compilation. It seems like this should only happen during the `test:compile` task. Is there a way to exclude `test` dependencies from being resolved and downloaded during the `compile` task?

Here is an example with the `org.mockito#mockito-all` dependency. I have it declared as test-only:

```
"org.mockito" %  "mockito-all" % "1.9.0" % "test"
```

However, when (clearing it from my local Ivy cache and) running `sbt compile`, it gets needlessly downloaded:

`$ sbt compile
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/rbrainard/.sbt/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/rbrainard/Development/spitball/project
[info] Set current project to spitball (in build file:/Users/rbrainard/Development/spitball/)
[info] Updating {file:/Users/rbrainard/Development/spitball/}spitball...
[info] Resolving org.mockito#mockito-all;1.9.0 ...
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mockito/mockito-all/1.9.0/mockito-all-1.9.0.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.mockito#mockito-all;1.9.0!mockito-all.jar (2075ms)
[info] Done updating.
[success] Total time: 7 s, completed May 28, 2014 4:51:20 PM`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sbt the `update` task resolves *all* dependencies for all configurations. Sbt makes use of Ivy, which promotes a very interesting "configuration" aspect to be able to separately resolve disparate classpaths at the same time.

Sbt is not only resolving your test classpath, but also runtime, the scala-tools (compiler, scaladoc, repl) and more.

Please read: https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/terminology.html for more information on the design of Ivy, which is why sbt attempts to do all resolution at once for all configurations.

Comment: So, it sounds like that's a 'no' :) Just wondering though because `last update` shows `confs: [compile, runtime, test, ... ]`. Can that not be updated?

Comment: You could modify the `allDependencies` setting to drop all the dependencies for confs you don't want.   Then you wouldn't be able to run tests until you undo that.

Comment: Ah, that sounds exactly what I need for this situation. I'll try that out.